# Why are Windows 7 (64 bit) clock desktop gadget hands not in centre?

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop-gadget

My clock gadget has been working fine for over a year since I installed Windows.

Now the clock gadget's hands have started to pivot from a position that is centred horizontally but not vertically.

When the minute hand is between around 20-40 minutes, this causes it to go beyond the edge of the clock. This causes a pink rendering artifact to appear.

In the following image, I have enabled the seconds hand so I can demonstrate the problem without having to wait until it happens again or adjusting my system time:

[image]

Things I've tried, with no success:

1. Removing it from desktop, rebooting, then re-adding
2. Uninstall the "Windows Gadget Platform" from Windows Features, re-installing it and re-adding the clock
3. Running `sfc /scannow` to check for damaged system files (none found)
4. Disk error check (none found)

I haven't installed any new software or drivers recently, only Windows updates.

Comment: Are you running legit copy of windows?

Comment: @tumchaaditya Yes.

Answer (score 0):

IE11 is the culprit. The gadgets apparently use the explorer rendering engine. If your desktop uses anything but 100% resolution, the gadgets will be drawn incorrectly.

Comment: Yep, just tried it now and it draws fine when the Windows text size is 100%. I had mine on 115%, but the resolution was 100%.

Answer (score 0):

The display scaling can be disabled for each gadget in its XML config file.
The locations are either `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets` or 
`C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets`

Open `gadget.xml` (inside the "gadget name"\"language code") subfolder with a text editor and look for the line `(autoscaleDPI)(!--_locComment_text="{Locked}"--)true(/autoscaleDPI)`.
Replace the `true` with `false` and save the file. The gadget has to be closed while editing the file.

Source: http://winaero.com/blog/fix-gadgets-displaying-broken-in-windows-8-1-or-windows-7-with-ie11/